# EFI settings cancel after boot from Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

I have Ubuntu 20 installed on my laptop as the second OS. I changed EFI settings in BIOS (of course, I saved them) and set ubuntu to the first place to choose which system I want to work with when my laptop turns on (I have a multiple choice contains ubuntu/windows boot manager).

But if I choose Windows and restart my laptop after working on this system, it will boot from Windows without ubuntu launcher giving a choice until I change my EFI in boot again (settings basically cancelled). Also when I restarted my laptop from windows I had some message about `node.exe` file (not quite sure that it is somehow connected with the issue). What is the problem?

Comment: Do not know if Windows or UEFI, but they sync BCD & UEFI on some systems. You may then need to add an entry into BCD. see https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/ 
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Comment: No idea about the message but I think I can help you with booting directly into Ubuntu, just in case oldfred's solution doesn't help. Head to your BIOS and after changing your boot hierarchy, change as well another option that says Hard Drive BBS Priorities, which may be set to Windows Boot Manager, and change it to Ubuntu.